# Why is my textbox getting a ghost value? HTML5/PHP

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a text box that seems to be getting a blank/space value when the form loads up. when i click submit and the form is validated it seems to be getting an additional space value. All other textboxes does not seem to be affected

Pics:

load up: http://prntscr.com/azmime

1st submit click: http://prntscr.com/azmit0

2nd submit click: http://prntscr.com/azmixw

These are the code related to the post code text box:

PHP:

```
<?php
$pCode = "";
$pCodeMsg = "";

$pCode = $_POST["postcode"];
    if (!empty($pCode)) {
        $pCodePattern = "/^(?:\d{4})?$/";
        if (!preg_match($pCodePattern, $pCode)) {
            $pCodeMsg = "<span> post code must be 4 digits </span>";
        }
    }
?>
```

HTML form:

```
<p>
    <label for="postcode"> Postcode (default 2000): </label>
    <input type="text" id="postcode" name="postcode" size=4 value="<?php echo $pCode; ?> "/>
    <?php echo $pCodeMsg; ?> 
</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<input type="text" id="postcode" name="postcode" size=4 value="<?php echo $pCode; ?> "/>`

see the extra space before the close " of the value ??

Fixed:

```
<input type="text" id="postcode" name="postcode" size=4 value="<?php echo $pCode; ?>"/>
```

Comment: thank you, ive been trying to figure out what was wrong for ages